# Could the 5.7 earthquake in Utah be a precursor to a larger one?

Tags: earthquakes

Trying to verify the validity of a rumor.

- https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/uu60363602/executive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, but the odds are small.

The USGS page that you linked to also links to a [forecast](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/uu60363602/oaf/commentary): "According to our forecast, over the next 1 Week there is a 1 % chance of one or more aftershocks that are larger than magnitude 5.7."

USGS also notes:

> No one can predict the exact time or place of any earthquake,
>   including aftershocks. Our earthquake forecasts give us an
>   understanding of the chances of having more earthquakes within a given
>   time period in the affected area. We calculate this earthquake
>   forecast using a statistical analysis based on past earthquakes.